# Call a rest api from one pod to another pod in same kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

In my k8s cluster I have two pods podA and podB. Both are in same k8s cluster. Microservice on pod B is a spring boot rest api. Microservice on pod A have ip and port of pod B in its application.yaml. now every time when  podB recreates, ip change which forces us to change ip in application.yml of podA. Please suggest a better way.

My limitation is : I can't change the code of podA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) will provide a consistent DNS name for accessing Pods.

An application should never address a Pod directly unless you have a specific reason to (custom load balancing is one I can think of, or StatefulSets where pods have an identity).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

You will then have a consistent DNS name to access any Pods that match the `selector`:

```
my-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: What if I have a cache clear endpoint and if request comes to any pod(say p1), I want to trigger the same cache clear endpoint on all other pods(p2,p3,p4...pn). How can I do this?

Comment: @theprogrammer Ask that as a standalone question, as it delves into your system design as well. In the Kubernetes specific design,  EndpointSlices (or the original Endpoints) are the layer down from services that represents all the pods selected for a service.

Answer (score 2):

That's what `service` are for. Take a postgres service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

You can use `postgres-service` in other pods instead of referring to the ip address of the pod. You also have the advantage that k8s's doing some load balancing for you as well.